# Delete from table where not in another table using two columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get my head around this delete statement I am trying to accomplish.  I understand how to delete from table where column not in ( subquery to table2)

I have two tables with multiple columns, and each table has two columns making up the primary keys. I think you have to do a join maybe?  I would like something in the lines of the following:

```
Delete From tbl1 left join tbl2
on tbl1.PK1 = tbl2.PK1 and tbl1.PK2 = tbl2.PK2
where tbl1_PK1 Not IN(
Select Distinct tbl2.PK1, tbl2.PK2 where DateStr >= GetDate()-365)
```

I am trying remove rows from tbl1.  Does this look close to correct?

Edit to add:

tbl1
PK1, PK2, Col1

tbl2
PK1,PK2, DateStr

```
Delete From tbl1 left join tbl2
on tbl1.PK1 = tbl2.PK1 and tbl1.PK2 = tbl2.PK2
where tbl1.PK1,tbl1.PK2 Not IN(
Select Distinct tbl2.PK1, tbl2.PK2 where DateStr >= GetDate()-365)
```

What is left after running sqlfiddle should be:

```
tbl1
('T', '222','asdf')

tbl2
('T', '222','9/26/2014')
```

Comment: On the Where Clause, I am trying to make the comparison to tb1_pk1 and tbl1_pk2 at the same time.

Comment: SHOW CREATE tbl1 (abd tbl2). Provide some sample DML (INSERT INTO tbl1 (tbl2) VALUES(...)) and then give us the result you want with the logic you used to get it. You could put all of this on SQLFiddle if that suits you. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using sql 2008.  I will make a sqlfiddle.  Thanks.

Comment: A little nitpicking: the DBMS you are using is called SQL **Server** 2008. "*SQL 2008*" is not a DBMS product - it's an ISO standard that defines the SQL *query* language

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7ef5/4  

above is the sql fiddle.  So anything older than a Year should be removed for this example.

Comment: Yes it's Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Could you also put the result you want (i.e. how the table should look after this SQL) here or on SQLFiddle. It's very confusing having columns you call PK1/2 and that they're not PRIMARY KEYs. Call them col1, col2 and col3. Also, I assume that tbl2.col3 is what you refer to as Datestr in the query?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you're after something like this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl1
FROM tbl1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2
        ON tbl1.PK1 = tbl2.PK1
        AND tbl1.PK2 = tbl2.PK2
        AND tbl2.DateStr >= GETDATE() - 365
WHERE tbl2.PK1 IS NULL
    AND tbl2.PK2 IS NULL
```

Yes, you have two `FROM` clauses with a multi-table `DELETE` statement. This is essentially just an anti-join turned into a deletion.

Comment: +1. No need for the 2 condition in the end. `WHERE tbl2.PK1 IS NULL;` is enough.

Comment: What is the purpose of the 'WHERE tbl2.PK1 IS NULL'

Comment: Can you check out this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0b50/13 doesn't seem to be removing any rows from tbl1. Nevermind, looks like the command works!  Thanks!

Comment: Now if I want to use the same rule for tbl2.  This should work? `DELETE FROM tbl2
where tbl2.DateStr >= GETDATE() - 366`  Probably not this simple. since this has the opposite effect that I wanted LOL  So I tried this `DELETE FROM tbl2
where tbl2.DateStr <= GETDATE() - 366` and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was able to figure it out with your help!  I can't vote up or else I would.

Comment: @ypercube Agreed, not necessary in this case. I just like to be verbose and always include the entire primary key whenever I'm dealing with a composite key.